# Why android gallery can share images on facebook and SHARE INTENT on my app only urls?

Tags: android, android-intent, share, android-facebook, android-sharing

As all we known, share intent is very limited with facebook, on facebook you only can share urls, you cannot share text and cannot share images, only urls.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://test.com");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

if you try this with facebook, it does not work:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

But... how its possible that i can share a image from my official android gallery on facebook?

I'm sure there is a way to share images on facebook like the official android gallery does. ¿How can it be achieved?

PD: i need to do it without facebook SDK, android gallery doesn't use facebook sdk.

Comment: I am interested in this as well - did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Specify MIME type also for the text. "text/plain" is the type of text data MIME. Try using "*/*" as MIME, so you can send any generic data type.

Also try changing ACTION_SEND to ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE which specialized for delivering multiple data.

More info about ACTION_SEND_MULTPLE and handling MIME types:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: no, not works!!! please, search in google "facebook share intent android not working". It is a known problem with facebook share intent of android, you only can share urls...

Comment: let me check it out as well

Comment: have you checked this link. though i does not totally agree with the answers but it is helpful

Comment: wich link? i can't see it